# Jboss As 5 and activemq

Tags: java, jboss, activemq-classic

Does anybody know how to configure Activemq on Jboss 5.1?
If so could he or she provide me with the example?

Many thanks for any answer!
Agata

Answer (score 5):

The instructions at this tutorial should help you http://activemq.apache.org/integrating-apache-activemq-with-jboss.html

Comment: I saw this one but isn't it for Jboss 4?

Comment: It works also for JBoss 5 (I ran it on JBoss 5). Please check my post to see the advancement in ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 4):

I just wrote up [my experience wiring up JBoss 5.1 (and JBoss ESB 4.5) to ActiveMQ 4.5.0](http://ttlnews.blogspot.com/2010/10/jboss-4551-and-activemq-54-integration.html), hope it clarifies some of the differences with the original activemq post.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this in a while so here goes.

1. Download the latest Apache ActiveMQ [here](http://activemq.apache.org/).
2. Unpack the archive that you've downloaded. There should be a `.rar` file included. Extract that rar file and unpack that into a directory.
3. Copy the extracted directory into JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy directory.
4. Start/Restart JBoss.

For more info check [here](http://activemq.apache.org/integrating-apache-activemq-with-jboss.html).

---

**PS** The latest ActiveMQ release (version 5.3.2 at the time of writing) doesn't require you to integrate ActiveMQ in any application server at all.

On `ACTIVEMQ_HOME/bin` run activemq and it will start on port 8161

the following will be deployed:

- admin
- fileserver
- camel
- demo

Also, there's a jar file you can use to communicate with ActiveMQ.

Comment: Well I think I didn't put write what I want to do.
I know that I can extract ActiveMq and run it without server and this is what I will do but I think I have to edit some config files in Jboss to point to queue, connectionfacotry and things like that. Than I want to configure it in Spring in my web app.
The part which is tricky for me is applying things in *-ds.xml files in Jboss, under deploy\messaging folder

Comment: Use the Jar file for communication to ActiveMQ. That allows you not to setup configuration scripts for Tomcat, JBoss, GlassFish, etc.